# Why doesn't GNOME respect OnlyShowIn=KDE; in .desktop files?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, kde, menu

I have both KDE and GNOME desktop environments installed on Ubuntu 10.10. When I add the entry `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;` in a .desktop file, the application doesn't appear in the KDE menu.

However, when I add `OnlyShowIn=KDE;` the file still appears in the GNOME menu. Does anyone know why this isn't working? Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Works here. Which file have you edited?

Answer (score 3):

Try running `sudo update-desktop-database` after you make any changes to the .desktop files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the whole Gnome story but you could use this in the meanwhile:

[Gnome Menu Extended (Debian package)](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/Gnome+Menu+Extended+(Debian+Package)?content=73515)

There's a KDE version too: [K Menu Gnome (Debian package)](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=31031)

Hint: read the Breaking news section in the first link. ;)